# Order Zend_Db_Table rowset by reference column

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table, table-relationships

i know i can define relationships through _referenceMap, i know that i con join selects trough

`$db->select()`

But what i need is to fetch rowset in model extending `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` and then order it by value of referenced column from another table.

Is there some workaround to do that?

**edit:**

heres is the example:

first table:

> table *bugs* columns *id*, *bugname*, *authorid*

second table:

> table *authors* columns *id*, *authorname*

I have a model `Model_Bugs extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`

I want to make something like this:

`$model->fetchAll($model->select()->order('authorname ASC'))`

This means, that i need to join tables and sort by a column, which is not in the model table.

thanks for help

Jan

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what you want to do. Can you provide some example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: In this situation I would create a method (e.g. fetchAllOrderedByAuthor) in the Model_Bugs that would do the join and return the correctly sorted rowset. I think you cannot do it using plain fetchAll method.

Comment: This is possible, but you cant do joins on zend_db_table, you have to make select with zend_db_select like this: `$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('p' => 'products'),
                    array('product_id', 'product_name'))
             ->join(array('l' => 'line_items'),
                    'p.product_id = l.product_id',
                    array() ); // empty list of columns` But then you cant use methods defined on a class extending Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract, because of the result.

Comment: Im thinking about mysql view to solve this problem...

Comment: @Jaroušek Puchlivec. You can do joints with selects using zend_db_table. For example, in your model: `$this->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART)->setIntegrityCheck(false)->join(....)`. mysql view would also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method in `Model_Bugs` like so:

```
public function fetchBugsByAuthorname() {

    $bugTable = $this;
    $bugTableName = $this->info('name');
    $authorsTable = new Model_Authors();
    $authorsTableName = $authorsTable->info('name');

    $select = $bugTable->select()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from($bugTable, array('id', 'bugname', 'authorid'))
        ->join($authorsTableName, 
            "$bugTableName.authorid = $authorsTableName.id", 
            array("authorname"))
        ->order("$authorsTableName.authorname asc");
    $result = $bugTable->fetchAll($select);

    return $result;
}
```

But to do this you have to turn off ZF's table integrity checking (`setIntegrityCheck(false)` above), which means you won't be able to directly call `save()` on the resulting rows.  But if it's for a read-only purpose, it will work.

If you needed to save rowsets back to the database, you may have to first select the author ID's from `Model_Authors` in the order you want them, and then re-order your `Model_Bugs` query accordingly.  It's messier but it can work.